# Second TableView not displaying any/correct nest array values

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

I have no errors but my second table view controller simply won't display the correct values (or number of values) segued from my first table controller.

Here's the full project if more insight is needed - https://www.dropbox.com/sh/77gs3bmxb77ul79/AAApV2m8Vh9Sc2FABiDzZRgha?dl=0

anyways, my code for the first table controller and second controller are shown below.

I have a feeling my issue is occurring with the naming conventions of my struct and new variable in the second controller "newrestaurant", in the prepare for segue function, or the "newrestaurant[indexpath.row].name" section of the cellforrowatindexpath function in the second controller.  Otherwise, the other code appears pretty straightforward.

Any help would be incredibly appreciated!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to assign segue identifier.

Click on your segue and Attribute Inspector at right hand side and assign segue Identifier as shown in below Image:

[image]

Comment: How were you able to decipher that so fast!  I was playing with this for at least half hour!

Comment: I just add some breakpoints and checked if it is entering in `if segue.identifier == "next"` condition and it was not so I checked segue In storyboard and found the issue.. :)

Comment: I should have thought of that.... haha.  Regardless, thank you for being clever and the help!

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)